# Ansible expect module unable to write data to a log file and connection closing after sometime

Tags: linux, ansible

Issue1: Unable to create log file with Ansible `expect` module.

I have a shell script which will prompt for a username and password when executing. I tried Ansible `expect` module. Below timeout: 10000 is for expect not to close the connection as this script is very long running one and I am OK to wait for this to complete. This is in seconds and default timeout for expect is 30seconds.

```yaml
- name: Register xyz agent and post install
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    command: "/path/to/myscript.sh"
    responses:
      (.*)Enterprise Manager Login(.*): "{{ oem_sys_pass }}"
      (.*)Agent Registration(.*): "{{ oem_agent_pass }}"
    timeout: 10000
```

As we do require a log for checking what is happening in the script, I used `>` which is a bad idea as it will redirect everything into a file instead of `STDOUT`.

```yaml
- name: Register xyz agent and post install
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    command: "/path/to/myscript.sh > /path/to/mylogs.log"
    responses:
      (.*)Enterprise Manager Login(.*): "{{ oem_sys_pass }}"
      (.*)Agent Registration(.*): "{{ oem_agent_pass }}"
    timeout: 10000
```

So I changed that to use tee command that way I will get my data into a log file as well as `STDOUT` as below.

```yaml
- name: Register xyz agent and post install
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    command: "/path/to/myscript.sh | /usr/bin/tee /path/to/mylogs.log"
    responses:
      (.*)Enterprise Manager Login(.*): "{{ oem_sys_pass }}"
      (.*)Agent Registration(.*): "{{ oem_agent_pass }}"
    timeout: 10000
```

But this is not creating any log file. When I run manually `/path/to/myscript.sh | /usr/bin/tee /path/to/mylogs.log`, I get logs into this file without any issue.

Issue2: is after sometime of execution, I am getting below connection closed error in Ansible logs.

```json
{"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to my.testmachine.com closed.\r\n",
```

Any thoughts on these two issues?

Trying to automate a script through Ansible `expect` module and it is not running as expected.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation about [`expect` module – Executes a command and responds to prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html)

> *If you want to run a command through the shell (say you are using `<`, `>`, `|`, and so on), you must specify a shell in the command such as `/bin/bash -c "/path/to/something | grep else"`.*